# Webpack dev server not using proxy

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server

I've read the [documentation](https://webpack.github.io/docs/webpack-dev-server.html#proxy) for the webpack-dev-server and how to setup a proxy, but it's not working for me. What I want to do is have an `API_ROOT` to `http://my_external_server.com/api` and then use that in ajax requests. In my config I have:

```
proxy: {
    'http://my_external_server.com/api/*' : {
        target: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/',
        secure: false
    }
}
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/g0614mzp/2/) is my full config.

Answer (score 3):

You just need to replace key with target like that:

```
proxy: {
  '/api/*' : {
    target: 'http://my_external_server.com',
    secure: false
  }
}
```